# ANTLR for c# behaves illogicaly

Tags: c#, antlr

Is there ANY reason why would ANTLR, for any reason, ignore tokens? Here's the relative code, i'm calling var_assign directly.

```
LABEL
    :   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;
fragment LOWER_CASE
    :   'a'..'z';
fragment UPPER_CASE
    :   'A'..'Z';
fragment LETTER
    :   UPPER_CASE | LOWER_CASE;

public var_assign 
    :   LABEL ':=' expression -> ^( VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT LABEL expression )
    ;
```

expression is the standard chain of expressions ending with tokens like NUMBER and LABEL (for variables), etc.

Now the issue is that i can just type "anything anything" and the parser will recognize that as an assignment.

```
ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream(input_to_process);
processor.lexer.ConsoleGrammarLexer Lexer = new processor.lexer.ConsoleGrammarLexer(Input);
CommonTokenStream Tokens = new CommonTokenStream(Lexer);
processor.parser.ConsoleGrammarParser Parser = new processor.parser.ConsoleGrammarParser(Tokens);

CommonTree start_rule_tree = Parser.var_assign().Tree;
//view the tree to help debug
processor_output = start_rule_tree.ToStringTree();
```

If i type "x 5", i get (VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT x 5)).
If i type "x:=5", i get (BLOCK (VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT x 5))
If i type "x*5", i get (BLOCK ,1:1], resync=x*5>)

This happens even if i send a constnat "string" directly into ANTLRStringStream.

I have managed to solve this by either replacing ':=' with (':=' | 'anythinghere') or (':=')*. But there are other odd behaviours.

I'm using CSharp3 as a language option and the newest .dlls.

What is going on, this makes absolutely no sense.

**EDIT:**

I've created a test grammar.

```
grammar testgrammar;

options {
  language = CSharp3;
  output = AST;
  TokenLabelType = CommonToken;
  ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

LABEL   :   'a'..'z';

WS  :   ' ' {Skip();};

public start
    :   if_statement EOF!;

if_statement
    :   LABEL ':=' LABEL ->^(LABEL LABEL);
```

Typing "ff" produces (f f), typing f*f produces a run-time error, typing f:=f produces (f f). What. The. Hell.

Answer (score 1):

The Java version gives:

```
/tmp $ java TestT
ff
line 1:2 no viable alternative at character '\n'
line 1:1 missing ':=' at 'f'
```

From:

```
    InputStream is = System.in;
    if ( inputFile!=null ) {
        is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    }
    CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);

    TLexer lex = new TLexer(input);

    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);

    parser.start();
```

Not sure what's up. CSharp3 should work too. I'm baffled.  Start the debugger and set a break point. It's your only hope, Luke!